# Postgres inside Docker container, how to log JSON to Loki via Promtail?

Tags: postgresql, docker, devops, grafana-loki, promtail

I have Postgres16.1 running in a container in Docker Swarm, alongside inter alia Promtail, Loki and Grafana. I want to direct Postgres logs in JSON format towards Promtail for easy processing in Promtail pipeline stages (especially of multiline logs). The setting Postgres config `log_destination=jsonlog` will create JSON logs in `log/postgresql-<DATE>.json` (see documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-JSONLOG)). But Docker stdout/stderr logs (which Promtail reads) will remain in default config.

docker-compose.yaml:

```
(...)
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: <from my local registry>
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all", "-c", "logging_collector=on", "-c", "log_destination=jsonlog"]
    labels:
      logging: "promtail"
(...)
```

How can I configure Postgres to log to stderr in JSON format? Also, is this a good idea/good practice in the first place?

Not having `stderr` as `log_destination` also does not seem to influence the stderr logging behaviour of the container.

Comment: I believe this question, being about configuration of existing application, is off-topic for SO. Consider one of: [su], [sf], [devops.se], or maybe even [dba.se]. But remember to check their respective help sections, to check if question belongs there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a straightforward solution that does not require volume mounting or other workarounds [here](https://serverfault.com/a/634296).

After having set `logging_collector=on`and `log_destination=jsonlog`, configure postgres `log_filename` to something static (exluding date/time as per default config) like `postgresql.json` [(see doc here)](https://serverfault.com/a/634296).

Then run the container with `ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/lib/postgresql/data/log/postgresql.json`.

This way, you shouldn't even have to worry about postgres log rotation, as the link will reroute to stdout directly and thus to docker log management.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `log_destination=jsonlog` is not about stdout/err.

Probably makes sense to add a sidecar container with one more Promtail looking for a mounted folder with Postgres JSON logs. Alternatively, but not recommended, you can use supervisord with 2 processes: one for postgress and the second for a bash script that `tail -f` logs. In this case, you'd need to turn off default stdout logs and rely on only `tail -f`. Also, you have to care about log rotation, which is challenging but seems doable.

One more extreme and less recommended way is to use [mkfifo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html) pipes to send logs to and simultaneously read them with `tail -f`. In this case, you don't need to care about log rotation.

Comment: Thought so too - using a shared volume seems pretty straightforward and you can use Postgres' log rotation. Would you suggest using an (additional) sidecar container per application container or just one central log shipper container (given a small cluster, maximum couple of GBs per day of log volume).

Comment: One central log shipper container is more common and straightforward. At least if the cluster is small, you can start with this design and see what will happen.